# Strip Base64-encoded URL parameters with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm decoding my URL parameters in .NET as explained in [this article](http://devcity.net/Articles/47/1/encrypt_querystring.aspx).
In some cases I need to get the URL parameters in Javascript. But the problem is that some parameter values end at a '='.

Example: *?itemID=Jj1TI9KmB74=&cat=1*

**Javascript function:**

```
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}

return vars;}
```

I know my problem is at the split-function in the for-loop but I don't know how to solve it.
I also used [jsuri](http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/) for this but the problem still exists.
Can I solve this in Javascript or do I need to reconsider my encryption-method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Having `=` unencoded in the URI query is invalid. You should escape it. However, for completeness, if you really needed to do this, try this:**

*Extra note: if you escaped the `=` using URI encoding, on the server side (e.g. $_GET) it'll be automatically decoded. With JavaScript and `location`, however, you must decode it first (`decodeURIComponent`) to work with it.*

Instead of doing:

```
hash = hashes[i].split('=');
```

where subsequent equals signs are split too, do this instead (a non-greedy match before the first equals symbol for the key name, the rest for the value):

```
match = hashes[i].match(/([^=]+?)=(.+)/);
key = match[1];
value = match[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Having an unencoded `=` in the URL is invalid. To do this right, you would have to additionally apply `encodeURIComponent()` on the base64 encoded data.

Whether the base64 encoding still makes sense then, is for you to decide.

Reference: [RFC 3986: Reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't control the process generating the =s? As Pekka said it's wrong.

However you could manually break the string at the first =, e.g.

```
var i = hashes[i].indexof('=');
if (i > 0)
{
    var key = hashes[i].substring(0,i);
    vars.push(key);
    if ((i+1) < hashes[i].length)
    {
        vars[key] = hashes[i].substring(i+1);
    }
}
else
{
    // No value
    vars.push(hashes[i]);
}
```